# Why can't I observe meta+i/meta+b in Safari?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

Please refer to this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ukS/1/)

As far as I can tell, this only applies to Safari on a Mac, so if you're using something other than that feel free to try it, but you probably won't notice any issue.

In an application I'm creating I need to observe command/meta+b & command/meta+i so I can make text either bold or italic. It works fine in chrome, but I can't observe those key combinations in Safari.

Is this a bug with safari? Am I overlooking something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

If the JSfiddle link doesn't give you the results I'm describing, then copy and paste the code below into a fresh jsfiddle and try the same experiment. Doing it this way ensures for me that the observe will not work. Regardless of the way it's applied in my application it refuses to observe the keystrokes.

```
document.observe('keydown', function(e) {     
     if(e.metaKey) alert('hi');
});​
```

Comment: Note that on Windows, `metaKey` is `false` when holding Ctrl.

Comment: I use ctrlKey for windows machines.